# Mask textbox multiple masks

Tags: vb.net, maskedtextbox

There're 4 options to input a phone number for my application

> 1. 0000-0000
> 2. 00000-0000
> 3. (00)0000-0000
> 4. (00)00000-0000

I'm using "Maskedtextbox" to handle with this, and I'm using this code:

```
Private Sub TB_Telefone_11_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TB_Telefone_11.KeyPress

        ' Format when lenght = 8     >     0000-0000

        If TB_Telefone_11.Text.Length = 8 Then
            TB_Telefone_11.Mask = "0000-0000"
            TB_Telefone_11.SelectionStart = Len(TB_Telefone_11.Text)

        ' Formart when lenght = 9     >     00000-0000

        ElseIf TB_Telefone_11.Text.Length = 9 Then
            TB_Telefone_11.Mask = "00000-0000"
            TB_Telefone_11.SelectionStart = Len(TB_Telefone_11.Text)

        ' Format when lenght = 10     >     (00)0000-0000

        ElseIf TB_Telefone_11.Text.Length = 10 Then
            TB_Telefone_11.Mask = "(00)0000-0000"
            TB_Telefone_11.SelectionStart = Len(TB_Telefone_11.Text)

        ' Format when lenght = 11     >     (00)00000-0000

        ElseIf TB_Telefone_11.Text.Length = 11 Then
            TB_Telefone_11.Mask = "(00)00000-0000"
            TB_Telefone_11.SelectionStart = Len(TB_Telefone_11.Text)
        End If

    End Sub
```

The problem is when the text is empty, returns the size of 10, this is because when it is blank, returns:

```
' Size of 10 with spaces and etc.
(  )    -
```

When you you're inserting numbers it works fine, but when you start to erase it stops in text.lenght = 10 and keep that mask.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `TextChanged` event instead. Also, add the case where the text length is less than 8 to reset the mask to an empty string.

```
    Private Sub TB_Telefone_11_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TB_Telefone_11.TextChanged

        ' Format when lenght = 8     >     0000-0000

        If TB_Telefone_11.Text.Length = 8 Then
            TB_Telefone_11.Mask = "0000-0000"
            TB_Telefone_11.SelectionStart = Len(TB_Telefone_11.Text)

            ' Formart when lenght = 9     >     00000-0000

        ElseIf TB_Telefone_11.Text.Length = 9 Then
            TB_Telefone_11.Mask = "00000-0000"
            TB_Telefone_11.SelectionStart = Len(TB_Telefone_11.Text)

            ' Format when lenght = 10     >     (00)0000-0000

        ElseIf TB_Telefone_11.Text.Length = 10 Then
            TB_Telefone_11.Mask = "(00)0000-0000"
            TB_Telefone_11.SelectionStart = Len(TB_Telefone_11.Text)

            ' Format when lenght = 11     >     (00)00000-0000

        ElseIf TB_Telefone_11.Text.Length = 11 Then
            TB_Telefone_11.Mask = "(00)00000-0000"
            TB_Telefone_11.SelectionStart = Len(TB_Telefone_11.Text)

        ElseIf TB_Telefone_11.Text.Length < 8 Then
            TB_Telefone_11.Mask = ""
            TB_Telefone_11.SelectionStart = Len(TB_Telefone_11.Text)

        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this but with that the text will not format correcly.

Comment: When you're typing, it works ok but when you're deleting it doesn't works because of text lenght.

Comment: @Heitor Badotti  - I am afraid this your code will never work with Mask. Suppose mask of length 8 is set. The user will not be able to type any more character, and so impossible to get to a longer mask. Current code more or less work because it does not take into account the special mask characters